# How to get only .pptx(MS - powerpoint) file through Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, powerpoint, filechooser

I have tried to use the following code but it's showing me all kind of files in the selection. I just want file chooser manu to show only .pptx(Powerpoint) files.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pptx");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_DOC_REQUEST_CODE);
```

A help would be appreciated!

Comment: Below link is clear your doubt Refer the link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002320/unable-to-pick-files-like-pdf-doc-ppt-in-marshamallow-file-chooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002320/unable-to-pick-files-like-pdf-doc-ppt-in-marshamallow-file-chooser)

Comment: try below link to get exact file format,[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304464/android-get-file-path-of-a-selected-pdf-doc-ppt-or-xls-in-my-app?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304464/android-get-file-path-of-a-selected-pdf-doc-ppt-or-xls-in-my-app?rq=1)

Comment: @Vadivel I have already tried that out! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution by myself by setting up the following mime-type.

```
intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
```

It works like a charm!